# produce multiple time series in different plot and save in working directory

Tags: r, loops

This appears quite simple but I have no idea how to go about it. My dataframe looks like this:

```
var1   var2  var3 var4 var5 var6 ..... var57
 1     23    67   89   63   34   .....  90
 2     34    43   43   23   23   .....  32
 3     45    65   45   32   54   .....  43
 4     45    32   18   61   87   .....  39
 5     23    74   53   54   76   .....  54
 6     21    65   34   34   12   .....  97
 .     .      .    .    .    .   .....  .  
 .     .      .    .    .    .   .....  .  
 .     .      .    .    .    .   .....  .   
365    54     78   54  12    90  .....  53
```

I want to produce separate plots and save them in my working directory for var1 against all the variables.

```
plot(var1 ~ var2)
plot(var1 ~ var3)
plot(var1 ~ var4)
plot(var1 ~ var5)
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .
plot(var1 ~ var57)
```

Is there any way to automate this so that I dont have to produce each individual plots at a time and then save it in my working directory?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try `?pairs`, e.g: `pairs(mydataframe)`. it will create scatterplot for all pairs of variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pdf("Plots.pdf")
for(i in 2:ncol(df)) plot(df[,1] ~ df[,i])
dev.off()
```

Comment: this is doing good but when I try to add lines over this, it gives me a blank plot                                                       pdf("Plots.pdf")
for(i in 2:ncol(grid)) plot(grid[,i] ~ grid[,1],type="n")
for(i in 2:ncol(grid)) lines(grid[,i] ~ grid[,1],col="red")
dev.off()

Comment: @user3013423 you need to add the lines right after you make the plot. Move both commands into the same loop. `for() {plot(); lines()}`